# Angular Js dependency Injection Issue

Tags: angularjs

I am facing with a dependency injection issue.Please help me  to resolve this issue.
I am trying to use  ngIdle to add user session expired concept to my application for these i add angular-idle.min.js as dependency plugin.Now actually my issue is when i am adding ngIdle dependency to app.js file where my all dependencies are initiated along with routing.When i run the application the ngdile is also affecting for login page which is not expected.So please help me how to load this ngidle dependency when i login into application.Actually its working but i need to skip this dependency for login page.
Thanks in advance,
Rajesh

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy to lazy load your dependencies when needed